# Loguru error when using dask with a multiprocessing scheduler

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, dask, loguru

I'm getting a `RuntimeError` when trying to log from a `dask.delayed` function using a logger handler with `enqueue` enabled.

Here's a minimal reproducible example

```
import sys, dask
from loguru import logger

logger.add(sys.stderr, enqueue=True)

@dask.delayed
def log():
    logger.info("Logging!")

dask.compute(*[log() for i in range(10)], scheduler="processes")
```

Which produces the following error:

```
RuntimeError: SimpleQueue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple. Import the logger from *within* your `delayed` function:

```
In [1]: import sys, dask
   ...: from loguru import logger
   ...: 
   ...: logger.add(sys.stderr, enqueue=True)
   ...: 
   ...: @dask.delayed
   ...: def log():
   ...:     from loguru import logger
   ...:     logger.info("Logging!")
   ...: 
   ...: dask.compute(*[log() for i in range(10)], scheduler="processes")
2022-09-13 21:42:36.001 | INFO     | __main__:log:9 - Logging!
2022-09-13 21:42:36.001 | INFO     | __main__:log:9 - Logging!
2022-09-13 21:42:36.001 | INFO     | __main__:log:9 - Logging!
2022-09-13 21:42:36.001 | INFO     | __main__:log:9 - Logging!
2022-09-13 21:42:36.002 | INFO     | __main__:log:9 - Logging!
2022-09-13 21:42:36.002 | INFO     | __main__:log:9 - Logging!
2022-09-13 21:42:36.004 | INFO     | __main__:log:9 - Logging!
2022-09-13 21:42:36.004 | INFO     | __main__:log:9 - Logging!
2022-09-13 21:42:36.004 | INFO     | __main__:log:9 - Logging!
2022-09-13 21:42:36.004 | INFO     | __main__:log:9 - Logging!
Out[1]: (None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None)
```